# Docker mount files to my local system while running the container

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I am using an image academind/node-example-1 which is a simple node image. You can check it https://hub.docker.com/r/academind/node-example-1 here. What I want while I run the image I want to get the same folder & file structure that is there in the Image. I know that can be done via volume. When I use like

```
docker run -d --rm --name node-test -p 5000:80 academind/node-example-1
```

Everything is proper But I want to get the codebase while running, so I tried like

```
docker run -d --rm --name node-test -p 5000:80 -v /Users/souravbanerjee/Documents/node-docker:node-example-1 academind/node-example-1
```

Here **node-docker** is my local folder where I expect the code to be. It runs but not getting the files in the local machine, I'm in doubt here where the source_path:destination_path. Please correct me to please tell me where I'm wrong, or what to do, or my entire thinking is going in the wrong direction or not.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the [official doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#volume-shared-filesystems), you'll see that the first part of the `:` should be the path somewhere in the host machine (which you're doing), while the later part should match the path "inside" the container (instead you're using image name). Assuming `/app` being the path (I've taken that course by myself and this is the path AFAIR), it should be:

```
docker run -d --rm --name node-test -p 5000:80 -v /Users/souravbanerjee/Documents/node-docker:/app academind/node-example-1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I also did that but that :/app is not also cloning the code, is there any other I need to do.

Comment: Cloning the code from inside the container to the host machine is something which has to be achieved with [`docker cp`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/) command.

Comment: Thanks, I don't have this course, I have just come up by searching, can u please ask in your course forum, on this, what is the proper approach, can't I do it with -v or the "cp" is the proper process?

Comment: `docker cp` is the way to go. If it doesn't work for you, it should tell you why. Try to retrieve that.

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct syntax is to enter the drive information in the volume mapping.

Eg. Users/xxxx/:some/drive/location

However, that would map your empty drive at xxxx over the top of 'location' folder. Thus deleting the existing files in the container.

If you are interested in seeing the contents of the files in the container, you should consider using 'Docker CP' command.

People often use volume mounts to push data (i.e. persistent database files) into a container.

Alternatively, writing log files to the volume mounted location inside the application container. Then those files are then reflected on your local drive

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the files to the current host directory using the command

```
docker cp node-test:/app .
```

when the container is running

Comment: Thanks, can't I do it with volume?

Comment: You can but it's more cumbersome. You can't get Docker to do it automatically with volume, so you'd have to mount your directory to a directory in the container other than `/app`. For instance `-v $(pwd):/copydest` and then go into the container and copy the files from `/app` to `/copydest`.